# How does version control with LabVIEW VIs work?

Tags: git, version-control, labview

Does anybody have experience with version control and LabVIEW? Since LabVIEW VIs are not text-based, how does it work? I would like to use git but I have a few questions:

- When committing changes, does git recognize the differences in the VI or does it replace the whole file with the new one? Does this result in a large expansion of the repository?
- Is there a possibility to merge different versions of a VI?
- Or is there a version control that works better for LabVIEW?

Comment: There are some helpful videos by Delacor on YouTube showing the basics of how to set up various version control systems with LabVIEW: https://www.youtube.com/user/unifab/videos?sort=dd&shelf_id=0&view=0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When committing changes, does git recognize the differences in the VI or does it replace the whole file with the new one? Does this result in a large expansion of the repository?

VIs are binary files, and so `git` will save the updated version as a new object. This can cause a LabVIEW repository to grow faster than a pure text-based source base.

> Is there a possibility to merge different versions of a VI?

Yes. There is a tool that installs with LabVIEW called [`LVMerge.exe`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/configmerge_thirdparty/) which can do this.

> Or is there a version control that works better for LabView?

I like and use `git` with LabVIEW. I also use these helpers:

- [LabViewGitEnv](https://github.com/joerg/LabViewGitEnv) -- for diff and merge
- [VIKit](https://github.com/wireddown/VIKit) -- to detect VI versions

Comment: As the NI link notes, you only get differencing and merging with the Professional development system or above, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

To be fair LabVIEW is more suitable with the SVN.

There is an easy way to integrate LabVIEW SVN merge and SVN diff in tortoise SVN.

Please [read](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1A300A1BB1833EE786257A7C0077B422) this article.

Also, there is a [toolkit](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/211524) for LabVIEW to work with SVN directly from a LabVIEW Project.

Here is the [help page](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-37416) explaining how to start working with Git.

You can setup **git diff** and **git merge** for LabVIEW.

Comment: I add that it is important to consider some Labview-specific caveats when using source control. Give a look here (Source Control Operations in LabVIEW): http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvconcepts/scc_operations/